# My Simple List only prints the last element of a .txt file

Tags: c, list

I have this code to print the content of a .txt file that includes the description, code-name, date and price of an unknown number of products (this is because it is supposed to work with any .txt file).
The problem is that my program only prints the last product of the .txt file. I don't know why that happens. Thanks in advance!

This is the program:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define LDES 32
#define LCOD 16

struct fecha { int d, m, a; };
struct ventas {
  char descripcion[LDES];
  char codigo[LCOD];
  struct fecha ultRep;
  float venta;
};
struct nodo {
  struct ventas d;
  struct nodo *sig;
};
nodo*primero = NULL;
nodo*ultimo = NULL;

void leerTexto(void) {
  nodo*nuevo = (nodo*)malloc(sizeof(nodo));
  char desc[LDES];
  char cod[LCOD];
  FILE *pf = fopen("ventas.txt", "r");
  if (pf) {
    fgets(desc, LDES, pf);
    while (!feof(pf)) {
        strcpy(nuevo->d.descripcion, desc);
        fgets(cod, LCOD, pf);
        strcpy(nuevo->d.codigo, cod);
        fscanf(pf, "%d/%d/%d", &nuevo->d.ultRep.d, &nuevo->d.ultRep.m, &nuevo->d.ultRep.a);
        fgetc(pf);
        fscanf(pf, "%f", &nuevo->d.venta);
        fgetc(pf);
        if (primero == NULL) {
            primero = nuevo;
            primero->sig = NULL;
            ultimo = nuevo;
        }
        else {
            ultimo->sig = nuevo;
            nuevo->sig = NULL;
            ultimo = nuevo;
        }
        fgets(desc, LDES, pf);
    }
    fclose(pf);
  }
}

void mostrarLista(void) {
  nodo* actual = (nodo*)malloc(sizeof(ventas));
  actual = primero;
  if (primero != NULL) {
    while (actual != NULL) {
      printf("%s\n", actual->d.descripcion);
      printf("%s\n", actual->d.codigo);
      printf("%d/%d/%d\n", actual->d.ultRep.d, actual->d.ultRep.m, actual->d.ultRep.a);
      printf("%f\n", actual->d.venta);
      actual = actual->sig;
    }
  }
}

int main(void) {
  leerTexto();
  mostrarLista();
  return 0;
}
```

This is the .txt file:

> Pizza
>
> 124g284j2
>
> 10/02/19
>
> 230.93
>
> Hamburger
>
> 27842yh28
>
> 23/09/23
>
> 197.00
>
> Carrot
>
> 283u1j23
>
> 31/12/17
>
> 89.98
>
> Ice Cream
>
> 3613y23u2
>
> 12/11/34
>
> 234.98

Comment: Read this: [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5431941/1679849)

Comment: You need allocate node each loop.

Comment: BTW You are using the C++ compiler as a C compiler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your C++ program, you have to put the node allocations inside the while loop. `fgets(desc, LDES, pf)` should also be inside the `while` loop.

Your filename probably has *.cpp extention, you are compiling in C++. You have to change the file extenstion to *.c, or you can set the compiler option to use C compiler.

The correct declaration in C is:

```
struct nodo* nuevo = malloc(sizeof(struct nodo));
```

You can put `fgets` call sequentially as they appear in input file. Use `fscanf(pf, "%f\n"...` to read the last character. Example:

```
if(pf) 
{
    while(fgets(desc, LDES, pf)) 
    {
        struct nodo* nuevo = malloc(sizeof(struct nodo));
        strcpy(nuevo->d.descripcion, desc);
        fgets(nuevo->d.codigo, LCOD, pf);
        fscanf(pf, "%d/%d/%d\n", 
            &nuevo->d.ultRep.d, &nuevo->d.ultRep.m, &nuevo->d.ultRep.a);
        fscanf(pf, "%f\n", &nuevo->d.venta);
        if(primero == NULL) 
        {
            primero = nuevo;
            primero->sig = NULL;
            ultimo = nuevo;
        }
        else 
        {
            ultimo->sig = nuevo;
            nuevo->sig = NULL;
            ultimo = nuevo;
        }
    }
    fclose(pf);
}
```

You can also add error check for `fscanf`. If `fscanf` is successful, it will return the number of items it reads. Example

```
if(3 != fscanf(pf, "%d/%d/%d\n",
    &temp.ultRep.d, &temp.ultRep.m, &temp.ultRep.a))
        break;
```

You have unnecessary allocation for `node` for in `mostrarLista`. It allocates memory for `actual`, but in the next line `actual` is set `primero` Now you have a memory leak, there is no way to free memory from malloc. You simply need

```
void mostrarLista(void) 
{
    struct nodo* actual = primero;
    while(actual != NULL) 
    {
        printf("%s", actual->d.descripcion);
        printf("%s", actual->d.codigo);
        printf("%d/%d/%d\n", actual->d.ultRep.d, actual->d.ultRep.m, actual->d.ultRep.a);
        printf("%f\n\n", actual->d.venta);
        actual = actual->sig;
    }
}
```